How do I properly resolve deprecations in Android Lint?
I will most likely encounter this problem for other methods/classes as well so it's more a general question not specific to MediaRecorder, it just serves as an example here.
I use android.media.MediaRecorder. Instantiating it with MediaRecorder() gives me the deprecation warning: Use MediaRecorder(android.context.Context) instead.
Since MediaRecorder(android.context.Context) was added in API 31 and my application supports API >= 30, i tried to extract the instantiation like this:
private fun createMediaRecorder(context: Context) : MediaRecorder {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 31) {
        MediaRecorder()
    } else {
        MediaRecorder(context)
    }
}

However, the MediaRecorder() line still gives me the deprecation warning. Can I properly resolve that warning without having to use a suppress annotation ? To me it feels like the deprecation tag on the constructor needs to be more specific here and say it's only deprecated on API >= 31 since there is no other way on API < 31 to use that constructor or am I missing something here ?
